# .hover() with jQuery works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My content box is disabled, I try to enable it with `.hover()`, but the problem is that `.hover()` works only on the first hover, not every time; content box class is `.dboxcontent`:

```
$('div.conbox').hover(function () {
    var activeID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + activeID + ' .dboxcontent').show();
}, function () {
    var activeID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + activeID + ' .dboxcontent').remove();
});
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nickyr3/qVuhh/7/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.hide()` instead of `.remove()`,
otherwise you are removing the DOM element with class `.dboxcontent` inside that hovered element.

Like this:

```
$('div.conbox').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.dboxcontent').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.dboxcontent').hide();
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgSG7/1/)

**Actually** you don't need jQuery for this, just CSS is the best solution here.

```
.conbox:hover .dboxcontent {
    display: block;
}
```

### Just CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pgSG7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need `.hide()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/qVuhh/10/

If you use the `remove()`method, the tag is removed.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a .remove() you are actually removing the HTML element from the DOM.

You should hide it instead.

I would rewrite your js this way:

```
                 $('div.conbox').hover(
                     function() {
                         $(this).find('.dboxcontent').show();
                     }, function() {
                         $(this).find('.dboxcontent').hide();
                     }
                 );
```

You don't need string concatenation there. You can use a .find() instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/qVuhh/9/

Comment: Have now learned difference between ".hide()" and ".remove()", many thanks